# Naming convention for variables like timers, counters, indices, etc?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, naming

I have a project in which I am organizing my variables/tags using categories like "PartA", "PartB", "Data", "HMI", and of course the requisite "Debug".

So a few examples of random tags would be:

```
Debug.ReadWriteTimer
HMI.ReportViewerMode    
Data.IndexResult
Data.ActiveDirectory
PartA.InspectionResult
```

But I have several variables that I am using across the program as logistical devices, such as counters, indices, and (non-debug) timers, that don't really fit in the the few categories that I listed above.

I've considered the following but none of those seem to fit either:

- Global.tagname
- Program.tagname
- Devices.tagname

What is a clear and logical naming convention for program-level "tools" like these that would be instantly recognized by someone looking over the tag database for the first time?

*(Context for the curious: this particular project is created using a machine vision software called Cognex Designer, which utilizes the C# language in an interface that is the illegitimate child of RSLogix and LabVIEW.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use "App", short for Application, as the category for these items. I believe it's clearer than "Program" and not easily confused with scope, like "Global", and the abbreviation will help alleviate confusion with .NET's Application object.

Answer (score 0):

misc, shortcut of miscellaneous, is/was often used to categorize items that couldn't be put in other categories.
This is if you must use a category, otherwise the lack of category perfectly describes the miscellaneous property of a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to find something more descriptive than "Misc" because I do believe these fall into a certain category; I just can't figure out what that might be. That said, if all else fails...

Comment: @DanA. yeah, I know I don't really answer your question, but there is no real connection between those in my eyes. I fear that you'll face the problem of yet another kind of unclassifiable variable soon enough. Still, maybe "technical" or "internal" would suit your needs better?

Comment: Yes, there is always the problem of that one pesky thing that doesn't seem to fit in any box... which is why I may end up using something generic like Misc or Global. Thanks for your suggestions! I'll wait to see if anyone else has any thoughts.

Comment: @DanA. I would advise against the use of global since it has a specific meaning about scopes, it could someday become confusing.